# Can I use Tomcat 8.0 in Eclipse Indigo 3.7.2?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat8

I'm doing a project right now, and I'm using Tomcat 7.0 running in Indigo Eclipse IDE, but I need to use Tomcat 8.0 because it supports servlet 2.4...

Well, I searched (and researched) a lot, but I only found answers and advice for others versions of Eclipse, like Luna, Sun, and stuff xD... but no Indigo was there.

When I tried to configure my server in Eclipse, it only showed the 7.0 version of Tomcat.

I'm starting with this, so I don't remember all of Eclipse's vocabulary...
Please help me. Thank you very much !

Comment: Joaquin, did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Sysdeo Eclipse Tomcat Launcher plugin maybe what you want.  You point it to an external Tomcat installation and it provides everything you'll need:

- ability to configure JVM Options (-D command line switches)
- a start/stop button in the Eclipse UI
- console output from Tomcat inside Eclipse
- debugging bindings so you can breakpoint a running Tomcat app

I've use it for years, works on all versions: 
http://www.eclipsetotale.com/tomcatPlugin.html